# Vue less loading css "Cannot read property 'denominator' of undefined"

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, npm, vue-cli

I have a style.less file that I am loading as follows

```
import "./styles/styles.less";
```

The file looks like the below, I needed to wrap the styles so they didnt effect the surrounding page and noticed the vue modal dialog css was not being loaded (hence why I moved them out to test at the bottom). This originally was because it couldn't find the bottom 3 imports.

```
.form-builder-app {
    @import './_variables.less';
    @import './_app.less';
    @import './_structure.less';
    @import './_page.less';
    @import './_section.less';
    @import './_question.less';
    @import './_controls.less';
    @import './_buttons.less';
    @import './_grid.less';
    @import './_modal.less';
    @import './_tooltips.less';
    @import './_questionProps.less';
    @import './_overrides.less';
    @import './_revert.less';
    @import './_viewMode.less';
    @import './_ie11-fixes.less';
    @import './_print.less';

}

@import '../../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
@import '../../../../../node_modules/bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css';
@import '../../../../../node_modules/vuejs-dialog/dist/vuejs-dialog.min.css';
```

The issue is when I run `npm run build` which calls the below in the package.json file it errors

```
vue-cli-service build --dest Areas/Builder/Vue/dist Areas/Builder/Vue/src/main.js"
```

It now finds the file in question but it errors with the following:

```
error  in ./Areas/Builder/Vue/src/styles/styles.less

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js):


  padding-right: calc(0.75em + 2.3125rem);
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='4' height='5' viewBox='0 0 4 5'%3e%3cpath fill='%23343a40' d='M2 0L0 2h4zm0 5L0 3h4z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e") no-repeat right 0.75rem center/8px 10px, url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='8' height='8' viewBox='0 0 
8 8'%3e%3cpath fill='%2328a745' d='M2.3 6.73L.6 4.53c-.4-1.04.46-1.4 1.1-.8l1.1 1.4 3.4-3.8c.6-.63 1.6-.27 1.2.7l-4 4.6c-.43.5-.8.4-1.1.1z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e") #fff no-repeat center right 1.75rem/calc(0.75em + 0.375rem) calc(0.75em + 0.375rem);
^
Cannot read property 'denominator' of undefined
      in C:\projects\Collaborator\Forms\ElectronicForms\ElectronicForms.Website\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.css (line 2291, column 2)
    at runLoaders (C:\projects\Collaborator\Forms\ElectronicForms\ElectronicForms.Website\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:316:20)
    at C:\projects\Collaborator\Forms\ElectronicForms\ElectronicForms.Website\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at C:\projects\Collaborator\Forms\ElectronicForms\ElectronicForms.Website\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (C:\projects\Collaborator\Forms\ElectronicForms\ElectronicForms.Website\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)

 @ ./Areas/Builder/Vue/src/main.js 8:0-30
```

I haven't a clue why this is happening, can anyone help please? cheers

Comment: Looks like `center/8px`. Try changing it to just `10px` or something, see if that fixes it. If so, you need to figure out where that variable center was supposed to be defined and why it's not.

Comment: Thanks AlexMA, appreciated the pointer, Deleting the whole line works, but believe this is pulled in via npm when I do an npm install. So not sure where to go from here, I did ask this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60930928/css-background-long-syntax-issue but got a code hitler not being any help and blocking a valid question!

Comment: Might be a bug in the library then, but doubtful. It's likely you're not importing the right thing. Only think I can think of is trying to import css directly out of the node modules dist folder looks fishy to me. I'd only do that if the docs for the npm lib tell you to.

Comment: OK Ill continue to have a play, appreciate the pointers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working my ignoring less and using scss instead. So it would seem that the less compiler/loader couldn't handle the boostrap css. Instead I now reference a new file e.g.

Import them in the **main.js** file

```
import "./styles/scss_styles.scss";
```

The scss_styles.scss file contents

```
// styling scoped to the form-builder-app so that it does not leak into the rest of the surrounding page
.form-builder-app {

    @import '../../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
    @import '../../../../../node_modules/bootstrap-vue/src/index';
    @import '../../../../../node_modules/vuejs-dialog/dist/vuejs-dialog.min.css';
}
```

This now works and allows me to scope the css just to the main control, instead of it leaking out into the surrounding page and messing up the original css.

```
<div class="form-builder-app">
    <div id="app"></div>
</div>
```

I could also have linked it to the #app id too, but just to show this approach does work.